# How to specify that a field containing an embedded document is optional but if provided, then certain fields are required?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-design, nosql, schema

```js
      nested_field: {
        inner_field: {
          type: Number,
          required: true,
        },
        inner_field_2: {
          type: Number,
          required: true,
        },
      },
```

How do I specify that `nested_field` is optional, but if it is provided then both of its inner fields are required?

Answer (score 0):

You can write function in the required field - [similar question](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5119)

```
required: function() { return //your_logic_here }
```

Comment: Do I need to add the `required` function to every field in the subdocument?

Comment: @freelionsntigersfromcages It depends on your requirements. there are few other ways of writing the functions you can check from [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-required)